# Javascript regular expression match on string followed by number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string of the format: `string:num` where num is any number but string is a known string that I need to match on.  I'd like to have this in an if statement as:

```
if( it matches 'string:' followed by a number) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: If you're shaky with Java regexes, tool around with http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/ :)

Comment: @Matt Ball: that site uses **Java** regexes; according to the tags, the OP is working with JavaScript.

Comment: Helpful question

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You want ...

```
if (stringYouHave.match(/^string:([0-9]+)$/)) {
    // do something
}
```

This includes:

1. `^` beginning of the string
2. `string:` the literal "string:" you mentioned
3. `(.....)` This subexpression, which you can refer to later if you need to know *which* number is in the string (though in this particular case, you could also just replace `'string:'` with `''`)
4. `[0-9]` *a* character between `0` and `9` (i.e., a digit)
5. `+` Must have at least one "of those" (i.e., digits mentioned above), but can have any number
6. `$` end of the string

Comment: +1 but the parens and the + could be more than required, depending on what exactly the OP wants - I'd explain the meaning for him.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple:- var temp= "select * from `Demo` AS `D1`, `Demo2` AS `D2`"; I want to select text after `AS` i.e D1 and D2 using regular expression.?

Comment: @Sanjiv That is not related to this question. To ask a new question, you want the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page.

Answer (score 5):

```
if( it.match(/^string:\d+$/) ( {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want only to check if the input string matches the pattern, you can use the [RegExp.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function:

```
if (/^string:[0-9]+$/.test(input)){
  //..
}
```

or with the [String.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/search) function:

```
if (input.search(/^string:[0-9]+$/) != -1){
  //..
}
```

If you want to validate and get the number:

```
var match = input.match(/^string:([0-9]+)$/),
    number;

if (match){
  number = +match[1]; // unary plus to convert to number
  // work with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above is good for integer numbers; if you want floating point numbers, or even scientific notation (as understood in C-like languages), you'll want something like this:

```
if (stringYouHave.match(/^string:[+-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$/))
{
    // do something
}
```

You can remove the first [+-]? if you don't care about sign, the (.[0-9]+)? if you don't care about floating points, and the ([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)? if you don't care about scientific notation exponents. But if there's a chance you DO want to match those, you want to include them as optional in the regex.

Comment: My answer does NOT force the string to match the full rules of scientific notation, which entails exactly one digit left of the decimal point. If you want that, you'll want something like

([+-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|[+-]?[0-9](\.[0-9]+)?([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?)

The first part, left of the "|" character, requires an optional sign, 1+ digits, and optionally a decimal w/more digits. The second part requires a valid scientific notation number, including only one digit left of the decimal.

You can change the "+" after the digits in decimal point to "*" if you want to allow for numbers like "5." as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(teststring.match(new RegExp("^" + knownstring + ":\d+$"))) {
  // some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!!"string:5456".match(/^string:\d+$/)) { ... }
```

Number is a integer in the example above.

Comment: Why would you put that double negation at the beginning?

Comment: To try and coerce a boolean out of it. You're better off using .test() here